# How to get groovy grape script startup going faster

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

I've noticed there is like a 10 second hit using a groovy script with Grape annotations on my OSX box. Is it always this way? Can I make grape favor its cache (the depedencies *are* definitely already on the system in ~/.groovy/grapes...).

Answer (score 2):

Some libraries (notably httpbuilder) use version ranges in their dependencies.  There is a post [here](http://spring-java-ee.posterous.com/fixing-slow-grab-dependencies-issue-with-groo) which describes how to increase the TTL for this version check in your grapeconfig.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a *~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml* file defined? The example given in the [doco](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape) favours the local cache.

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="downloadGrapes"/>
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="downloadGrapes">
      <filesystem name="cachedGrapes">
        <ivy pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
        <artifact pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
      </filesystem>
      <!-- todo add 'endorsed groovy extensions' resolver here -->
      <ibiblio name="codehaus" root="http://repository.codehaus.org/" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="java.net2" root="http://download.java.net/maven/2/" m2compatible="true"/>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Comment: Yeah thats pretty much what my configuration looks like - except I have a few extra 'ibiblio' references for different repositories down at the bottom.

Comment: In your groovy script have you declared a dependency on the latest version of a library? In this case Groovy might be checking the internet to determine if there's anything new to download.

Finally you could set the property -Dgroovy.grape.autoDownload=false to tell Groovy not to download anything